# copy file and create symlink using ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

On the source machine where i am running the playbook cmd i have a cert file and i have linked that with the hash value. Now i wanted to copy that to my client machine. What command should i use copy and preserve the symnlink.

Source machine

```
/home/ca.d
cacert.pem
e2223e235.0 -> cacert.pem
```

Destination source where i wanted to copy and link

```
/etc/syslog-ng/ca.d
```

I am using the below command to copy the cert but i am unable to find the cmmand to link it

```
- name: copy files
  copy: src=/home/ca.d/{{ item.src_name }} dest=/etc/syslog-ng/ca.d/{{ item.dest_name }}                               
  with_items:                                                                                   
    - { src_name: cacert.pem, dest_name: cacert.pem }
```

Comment: [file](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/file_module.html) module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a symlink in Ansible you use the [`file` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/file_module.html) with `state: link` argument. You won’t be able to do it in a single task, so you need to add another one after the copy:

```
- file:
    src: /etc/syslog-ng/ca.d/cacert.pem
    dest: /etc/syslog-ng/ca.d/e2223e235.0
    state: link
```

<sup>Your data doesn’t specify how you get the symlink name, so the above example uses hardcoded values, replace them accordingly.</sup>

Comment: I tried but i get the below error. Do i need to create a file e2223e235.0 and then do symlink

 "Error while linking: [Errno 2] No such file or directory", "path": "dest=/etc/syslog-ng/ca.d/e2223e235.0"

Comment: It worked. followed the same syntax you posted above.thank you!